# how can i change Xunit option in hudson/jenkins

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

i Use jenkins with Xunit publisher plugin.

> > my problem is that jenkins take just a new report (he have a interval to know if the report is new or old one ) , so when i build ,and i need to say that i generate report with line commande so is not really syncronised .
> >
> > so i want to configure the plugin to have the possibility to set up the time ( like say to jenkins take all report 15min older).

thnks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the reports are sometimes generated after the publishing step.

If you do not want to adapt the build process itself (e.g. generate the reports with the [maven surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/) or similar), you can define the report generation as a pre-build-step by calling a separate script or a goal/phase.

EDIT: if reports are found, but are stale, try what happens, if you run the clean target as the first step? Are the reports found? the error message sounds like if the tests were actually stale.

As to the not found file - Try an absolute path once to clarify the presence of the file. If everything runs smoothly, the problem lies in the assumption of the execution directory for the relative path.

Comment: ts a exemple of returned message >>Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run?

Comment: and to make the report as a pre_build , i tried that with a commande, but i have a problem ith this commande in jenkins .i explain:
i need to call my file like that :
php /path/index.php arg=valueArg arg2=ValueArg2 ..
and when i use this commande he say , could not open input file , and i want to underline the fact that the same commande work in my CLI XP windows. thnks for your anwser

Comment: okey i understand what you mean , i need to know how to execute the commande line that i show you 
php path/index.php arg1=valueArg1 in a batch task in jenkins , cuz he dont accept this kind of calling
c:/project/path/path/index.php .... i give absolute one and it dosent work
i give all the link like :